# C++ substitution of ios::noreplace

Tags: c++, std, fstream

I'm using fstream to open a file for write. I don't want to overwrite an existing file so after some searching, I found ios::noreplace. But when I compile this:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//......Did something else.
ofstream fout;
fout.open(outputFile,ios::noreplace);//outputFile is a C string
```

I get an error

```
 error: ‘noreplace’ is not a member of ‘std::ios’
```

I'm just wondering is there any std:: subsitution for ios::noreplace?

Comment: And what do you want to do when the file _does_ exist? What's wrong with append mode?

Comment: My program is to process some codes so it's not acceptable to append codes after something else. In fact what I'm trying to do is to avoid users from accidentally damage their existing files.

Comment: So, _what do you want to do_? Open in read-only mode when the file exists already, but writeable mode when it doesn't? Or what? You never explained. And what "codes"?

Comment: abort when file exists. write when file doesn't exists.

Comment: Why is this detail not in your question? It's fundamental.

Comment: Ok. Next time I will pay attention to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some searching on the internet reveals that you can add an existence check manually by attempting to open in "input" mode:

```
std::fstream myfile("thefile.txt", std::ios::in);

if (myfile)
{
    // error, file exists!
}
else
{
    myfile.close();
    myfile.open("thefile.txt", std::ios::out);  // OK now
}
```

Comment: Blatant and easy. Except that I need to open the file twice... Thanks. Thanks to others too.

Comment: @YankeeWhiskey: No way around that. Any sort of low-level operation with "noreplace" would have a similar sort of redundancy anyway, you just wouldn't be aware of it.

Answer (score 6):

The suggested answers are risky since they have race conditions.
Unless you can guarantee nobody will ever create that file while your are running this test, you should not use it.

As a workaround, use the non-portable method (on Linux for example open with O_CREAT|O_EXCL).

You can either use the resulting handle with code like boost to wrap it into an ofstream, or in this case use open() only to check and then create a new ofstream on the file (the latter assumes nobody deletes/renames the file in-between and thus might still have a race condition).

C++ not providing ANY safe way to create a file is a bad joke and likely the cause of quite a few security holes. You have to love standards that encourage bad practices by making writing correct code impossible.

Answer (score 6):

The complaints are addressed! C++23 finally standardises the `std::ios_base::noreplace` flag to open a file for writing in exclusive mode, i.e. to fail if that file already exists.

Paper: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2467r1.html

Common standard library implementations are already supporting this in C++23 mode, including `libstdc++` as bundled with GCC/`g++`.

Answer (score 5):

`noreplace` never got into the standard.  About four seconds of googling yields:
http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14544

> In pre-standard C++, certain implementations of  offered the flags ios::nocreate and ios::noreplace for controlling file creation. These flags were too platform-specific and never made it into the standard  library, which supersedes the deprecated, pre-standard  header. However, you can achieve the functionality of these obsolete flags rather easily.

```
fstream fs(fname, ios_base::in);// attempt open for read
if (!fs)
{
    // file doesn't exist; create a new one
    fs.open(fname, ios_base::out);
}
else //ok, file exists; close and reopen in write mode
{
     // Should throw an error
}
```

Comment: No wait, this makes no sense to me. Both clauses do the exact same thing, expect that one also opens and closes a file completely unnecessarily.

Comment: The second clause closes the first fstream open for read before reopening for write, but I don't see why you couldn't just open it for write to begin with.  Hrm.

Comment: `noreplace` was added to C++23 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode