# What is the difference between ios::app and ios::noreplace modes in file handling?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, file-handling

I am studying File Handling in C++, but I am unable to see the difference between ios::app and ios::noreplace modes. Kindly help.

Note: ios::noreplace is a non-standard mode in some older version yet I am curious to know about it!

Comment: I don't think there is anything called `ios::noreplace` in standard C++. So that would be a difference.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode - never heard of `ios::noreplace`.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251581/c-substitution-of-iosnoreplace

Comment: In pre-standard C++, certain implementations of <fstream.h> offered the flags ios::nocreate and ios::noreplace for controlling file creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `ios::noreplace` was a nonstandard part of some old version of the MS run-time library. It was added to [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), so there's one difference to begin with.

The other difference is that `ios::noreplace` does not append at all: It simply fails if the file is present (thus the name no replace) and opens it only if it did not exist in the first place. `ios::app` opens the file if present or creates a new one and seeks to the end before each write.

Comment: PalakJain   The appropriate thing to do in SO behaviors would be to ACCEPT the answer that @Fozi provided you.  "Thanks" is appreciated but the 'accept' is the proper thing to do.

Comment: _"IIRC ios::noreplace was a nonstandard part of some old version of the MS run-time library."_ Not just MS, it was in the Roguewave library, and UNIX System Labs I/O Streams, and probably **all** iostreams libraries before ISO C++98.